# How to create DataBase Configuration as library in Mule 4?

Tags: mule4

I have a big Monolithic Oracle DB. I may end up creating around 20 System APIs to get Various data from this DB. So instead of configuring DB connection in all 20 system APIs, like to create a DB connector and make it as a jar file. So that every system APIs can add this in their POM and use that for connection.

Is that something possible or is there any better approach to handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method if all applications are in the same server is to create a domain and share the configuration by placing it in the domain. This is usually the recommended approach. This method is documented at https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/shared-resources

If that's not possible (for example CloudHub doesn't support domains) or desired, then you have to package the flow in a jar by following the instructions in this KB article: https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-add-a-call-to-an-external-flow-in-Mule-4. Note that while the article title mentions flows, the method works with both configurations and flows.

Comment: Option 1 : Do you have any documentation for me to read and understand little bit more on this option.
Option 2 : Here i dont need entire flow . I just need to share the only DB Connection details.

Comment: I have updated the answer with the response to your questions.